# Backbonejs conditional route for wizard

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, wizard

I'm trying to create a little wizard with backbonejs in which the answers to certain questions determine the path being taken through the wizard. Is there a way in backbonejs to assess the current state of the model and navigate to the next page accordingly? Or is there another way of accomplishing this best in a backbonejs kind of way?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to treat each answer as a different route. That way when the user selects an answer, the route is change and you can load/change views accordingly in your router. Be sure to make use of variables in routes like

```
routes: {
        ":question/:answer": "checkAnswer"
    }
```

Where question and answer are variables

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, so `checkAnswer()` would route to the appropriate handler calling `app.navigate("#/handler1")` (or another one depending on the answer)? What if the user tries to use the back button of the browser? Wouldn't it then route back to `checkAnswer()` which automatically calls the navigate method? You wouldn't be able to go back this way, I think...

Comment: If the question alone has a url then you need another one
":question": "showAnswers"

That way you can show the question to the user the after the user answers that question, you move to the checkAnswer url

Answer (score 0):

You can have your router subscribe to the model's "change" or "change:[attribute]" event, then change the route and page accordingly

OR whenever you want to go to a new page call the router's navigate function

```
router.navigate("question1/option1", {trigger: true});
```

This will change the url and also trigger the route you set up for "question1/option1"

So if your router is:

```
router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:  {
       "question1/option1": "answer1"
    },
    answer1: function() {
        //change the page / or take whatever other action you want.
    }
```

answer1 function will be called to setup your next page.